# How to find overlap values within two ranges

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have two ranges. I am trying to find out if there is an overlap in their values. Is there built-in 'application' function that finds if the values within the two ranges overlap? Or do I need to do something like this, where I have two sets of for-loops and some sort of logic that tests if `rcellA` (cells in range A) overlap with `rcellB` (cells in range B)?

```
Set rngA = loopset.range("A2-A999")
Set rngB = loopset.range("B2-B999")
For Each rcellA in rngA.cells

    For Each rcellB in rngB.cells

    Next rcellB

Next rcellA
```

Comment: @Gary'sStudent OP is asking to check if values intersect and not address if I am right.

Comment: you need to have 1 `For` loop, and replace the second one with `Application.Match` function

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what kind of overlap you're actually after

So here some shots

Return the number of cells in two ranges with same relative position and value:

```
Function CheckRangesOverlap1(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, overlaps As Long) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long, firstColumn As Long, iRow As long, iColumn As Long

    firstRow = rng1.Rows(1).Row - 1
    firstColumn = rng1.Columns(1).Column - 1
    For Each cell in rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        iRow = cell.Row - firstRow
        iColumn = cell.Column - firstColumn
        If rng2(iRow, iColumn).Value = cell.Value Then overlaps = overlaps + 1
    Next
    CheckRangesOverlap1 = overlaps > 0
End Function
```

Return range of cells in two ranges with same relative position and value:

```
Function CheckRangesOverlap2(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, overlapRng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long, firstColumn As Long, iRow As long, iColumn As Long

    firstRow = rng1.Rows(1).Row - 1
    firstColumn = rng1.Columns(1).Column - 1
    Set overlapRng = rng1.Offset(rng1.Rows.Count).Resize(1,1)
    For Each cell in rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        iRow = cell.Row - firstRow
        IColumn = cell.Column - firstColumn
        If rng2(iRow, iColumn).Value = cell.Value Then Set overlapRng = Union(overlapRng, cell)
    Next
    Set overlapRng = Intersect(overlapRng, rng1)
    CheckRangesOverlap2 = Not overlapRng Is Nothing
End Function
```

That you can exploit in tour "Main" function as follows:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim loopset As Worksheet

    Set loopset = WorkSheets("myLoopsetSheet")
    With loopset
        Set rngA = .range("A2-A999")
        Set rngB = .range("B2-B999")

        Dim overlaps As Long
        If CheckRangesOverlap1(rngA, rngB, overlaps) Then
             ' your code to handle overlaps number
        End If

        Dim overlapRng As Range
        If CheckRangesOverlap2(rngA, rngB, overlapRng) Then
             ' your code to handle overlapRng range
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @nas, did you get through it?